# JAVA SPRING MVC Modify output stream before showing on the page

Tags: java, spring, interceptor

is there a proper way how I can modify output content right before Spring flushes it to the page? When content is ready I need to run a regex to fix all the links at ones.

Lets say I use interceptors, how do I get the rendered content, modify it and set it back ?

```
public class SpringControllerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("postHandle");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Filter` layer to process your response, You can grab whole response body and process the links you want

Comment: let me guess... you would have answered "yes" if stackoverflow allowed a answer that short.

Answer (score 0):

Spring MVC Interceptor would be the one of the way of doing this. Override [postHandle](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html#postHandle%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,%20java.lang.Object,%20org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView%29) method to update the http response object.

```
void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response,
                Object handler,
                ModelAndView modelAndView)
                throws Exception
```

Intercept the execution of a handler. Called after HandlerAdapter actually invoked the handler, but before the DispatcherServlet renders the view.

Read more:

1. [Spring MVC Interceptor example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/)
2. [Spring Interceptor
   Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

Comment: Right, but inside interceptor how to I get actually rendered content, modify it and set it back ?

Comment: For that you may have to extend class `HttpServletResponseWrapper` and use decorator pattern to get the content before you update and send to client. See example code: http://lexis.livejournal.com/3388.html

Comment: @ViralPatel Unfortunately, this decorator pattern approach is not working in my case. I've poured out my woes in this stackoverflow question at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14092997/349667). Can you please suggest any ideas?